Как через цикл добавить значения TextBox в документ excel VBA (Visual Basic)
'Кнопка добавить данные
Public Sub ButtonAdd_Click()
 Dim i, n, k As Integer

 n = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
 k = n + 3
 For i = 1 To 4
    Cells(n, i + 1).Value = " & TextBox & i & "   
    Next
'Без цикла это работало так
        'Cells(n, 1) = TextBox1
        'Cells(n, 2) = TextBox2
        'Cells(n, 3) = TextBox3
        'Cells(n, 4) = TextBox4
        
End Sub


Можно обратиться к коллекции Controls формы
ActiveSheet.Cells(n, i + 1).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value


Спасибо за идею. Но выдается ошибка "Невозможно получить свойство OLEobjects класса Worksheet"

Да, можно. Как это сделать?

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/xmwRcMOwBI8Czg

Спасибо! Всё работает. Можете объяснить Me, это что или что загуглить, чтобы об этом почитать?

Me - это ссылка на объект, соответствующий модулю. Если применять в модуле формы, то ссылка на объект формы. Если в модуле листа, то это ссылка на лист. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword
